# Why use the logarithm of the relative error?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, poissons-equation

In my numerical analysis course, we had an assignment to use MATLAB to numerically solve the Poisson Equation $-\nabla\cdot\nabla u = 0$ in one dimension.

We computed the numerical solution, plotted against the given closed form solution, and and then were told to "calculate the logarithm of the maximum relative error":

$$E=\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\log_{10}\left(\left|\frac{v_i-u_i}{u_i}\right|\right)$$

where $u$ is the closed form solution and $v$ is the numerical.

What's the idea behind taking to logarithm of this error?

Comment: If the error is $10^{-k}$, the logarithm tells you the $k$. This is an informative way of zooming in on very small numbers, especially if these numbers have widely different scaling. One other advantage is that if the error looks like $C h^n$ (typical for a lot of numerical methods), then the log of it looks like $\log(C)+n\log(h)$, so you can in principle read off the order of your method from a log-log plot of $h$ vs. the error.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation behind using a relative error measure with IEEE 754 hardware is to determine the order of magnitude by which the mantissa ($d_1.d_2d_3…d_k$) differs between result and solution. (In other words: how many machine numbers lie between the computed result and the actual solution)

In practice, a computer could just compare both mantissa and evaluate their difference. However, to maintain continuity and to also factor in a value’s proximity to adjacent scales, the absolute error is divided by all of x and not just its order of magnitude $\beta^{e}$.

As a result, $$log_{10}([\![v_i-u_i]\!]_{rel})$$ gives an **approximation for the number of correct digits in $v_i$**.